# Switching connection string on datacontext

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have a *VB.NET* solution file on *VS2010* with the following format

```
Code.Business (Business layer) .vb classes.
Code.Data (Data layer) LINQ to SQL .dbml files. 
Code.Web (UI layer) - ASPX pages.
```

I have a `datacontext` in my data layer and have a default constructor that changes

```
Public Sub New()
MyBase.New(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConStr").ConnectionString, mappingSource)
OnCreated()

End Sub
```

Now this `datacontext` is used from all the web pages through business layer vb classes.

I am trying to switch to correct database *(Dev/Test/Prod)*. I wanted to use the above constructor and pass the correct values for *("MyConStr")* so that it could point to the correct database.

I have all the three values *(Dev/Test/Prod)* on my *`web.config`* file.

In *`Global.asax - Application_Start event`* I am reading the values from `web.config` to a application variable.

```
 Dim strDBCon As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(strServer & "_connstr")
 Application("ConString") = strDBCon
```

I tried the *Application(`"Constring"`)* and the value didn't seem to be retained and I am not able to switch the value on my default constructor of `datacontext`.

Has anyone has a better solution for this scenario?

Comment: The default constructor is in partial class on the Code.Data project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `partial class` for your data context.please see `Handling Multiple Result Shapes from SPROCs` of this link:

[LINQ to SQL (Part 6 - Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

I think you can use `partial class` for write your own constructor